# Mirroring controller content

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller which uses the `content` as a base, and then has another variable called `items` which is a filtered version of the content. The `items` should be updated when the `content` is updated. I tried doing something like this in my controller:

```
updateItems: function() {
  var items = this.get('content').filter(this.get('toggleFilter'));
  this.set('items', items);
}.observes('toggleFilter', 'content'),
```

This works nicely, except on the first load. When first browsing to the page, items is empty. I gather this is because in the setupController it is set to `content` which is still waiting for information.

I noticed that setting the observes to `content.length` makes it work. However, this isn't ideal, partly because the `updateItems` method will be called for each insert when the data is loaded, and also because the content might change, but the length might stay the same. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@each` is what you're looking for

```
updateItems: function() {
  var items = this.get('content').filter(this.get('toggleFilter'));
  this.set('items', items);
}.observes('toggleFilter', 'content.@each'),
```

Also, you can use computed property as follows

```
items: function(){
  return this.get('content').filter(this.get('toggleFilter'));
}.property('content.@each', 'toggleFilter')
```

After `isLoaded`

```
items: function(){
  return this.get('content').filter(this.get('toggleFilter'));
}.property('content.isLoaded', 'toggleFilter')
```

Comment: On initial load, the items from the model are inserted one by one. So for an item set of 1000 items, that function will be called 1000 times. Is there not a way to call the updateItems once all the content information has been loaded?

Comment: Ember runloop is smart enough to tackle the case when 1000 items are inserted at once, it wont get executed for every single addition it'll get executed after the 1000th element, but again if those items were added at different point of times then it'll get executed at that time, you can check this behavior by adding a console.log or alert

Comment: I tried using your property suggestion and its much more elegant. It also solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: If you are looking to execute it after all the data is loaded then check the updated answer